# Add condition within String statement in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

In my code, at run time i can get num value as zero so want to add condition like if num value is zero then skip one of the sub statements otherwise add in string statement.

```
String Statement = 
"Timer Main\r\n"
"Sharm                \tv7 (" + IntToStr(Value) + ")\r\n"
"Get All Values     \t" + FloatToStr((float)GetAllValues/50, 1, 2) + "\r\n"
"Sum of Values    \t" + FloatToStr((float)SumOneValue/50, 2, 4) + "\r\n"
"% for     \t" + FloatToStr(((float)num)*100.0, 12, 
2) + "\r\n\r\n"
            "--------------------------------\r\n"
```

Comment: Have you tried a ternary expression with an empty string?  `(num==0) ? "" : something_else_here`

Comment: `+ FloatToStr(((float)**num**)` -- Don't use the `*` character as an emphasis tool.  The `*` will get confused with an actual pointer dereference or multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string stream:

```
#include <sstream>

...

std::stringstream s;
s << "Timer Main" << std::endl << "Sharm \tv7 (" << IntToString(value) << ")" << std::endl;
// ...
if (num == 0)
{
    s << "";
}
else
{
    s << "!= 0";
}
// ...

std::string statement = s.str();
```

The advantage of doing this is that you can create your string in multiple steps, so having conditional checks is easier. You can also use the formatting options provided by iomanip, like filling with spaces etc.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator can be used to write that compact:

```
bool  condition = false;
std::string str = std::string("hello") + (condition ? std::string(" true string") : " false string") + " world";
std::cout << str;
```

output:

```
hello false string world
```

Though, the conditional operator is also a great way to write unreadable code and you should probably just do this:

```
std::string str2 = "hello";
if (condition) str2+= " true string";
else str2+= " false string";
str2+=" world";
```

Simply don't try to squeeze everything in a single statement.